# JSX element type 'ReactElement<any> | null' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have simple `Paragraph` component set up in a following way

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

const { memo } = React;

/**
 * Component
 */
function Paragraph({ children }) {
  return (
    <Text>
      {children}
    </Text>
  );
}

export default memo(Paragraph);
```

Whenever I use `<Paragraph />` in my application I receive following error from typescript:

> JSX element type 'ReactElement | null' is not a constructor
>   function for JSX elements.   Type 'ReactElement' is not
>   assignable to type 'Element'.ts(2605)

This happens to a lot of my elements and started happening since I updated to lates typings for react and react-native from definitely typed. I'm unable to pinpoint a change that might be causing this error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is caused by different versions of typing libraries in the autogenerated files, probably messed up by updating it, remove `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` then reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

Small tip: when it happens, it's easier to see where the error is coming from when you provide the component return type explicitly (here: `React.FC`):

```
const Paragraph: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
  <Text>
    {children}
  </Text>
);
```

If the error says something about the `<Text />` component not returning `ReactElement<any> | null`, you know that component is the culprit. If not, it's most likely about types not being in sync just like @ramirozap suggested.